# Store each object of a JavaRDD to S3 based on one of the fields in the object

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-s3, rdd

I have a Java object as follows:

```
public class Obj {
   String id;
   String name;
   String date;
}
```

Now, I have an RDD of Obj, let's call it `objRDD`. I want to store this RDD to s3. Doing `objRDD.saveAsTextFile(s3path)` stores the entire output to the same folder. But, I want to store each RDD object based on the `date`. So my question is how can I have a path for each RDD object based on the `timestamp`. So objects with date, for example, 2021-07-27 come in one folder and similarly others.

So essentially the s3 structure should look like

```
bucket/objFolder/date=2021-07-27/part-0000, part-0001
bucket/objFolder/date=2021-07-28/part-0000, part-0001, part-00002
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first aggregate the rows by `date` and collect the dates. Then iterate over these dates, filter and write inside the loop.

I am not familiar with Java RDD. So I write in PySpark SQL as pseudocode instead, but the concepts should be similar:

```py
df = df.cache()

rows = df.groupBy("date").count().collect()
dates = [r["date"] for r in rows]

for date in dates:
    df.filter(f"date = {date}").write.parquet(f"s3://xxx/xxx/date={date}")
```